# Hide last column in range and clear cells

Tags: excel, range, cell, vba

I have a checklist workbook that allows you to check multiple items within a work order. The maximum amount of items is 15. I have a piece of code that will allow me to hide the columns, starting from the farthest right, that are not needed but cannot figure out how to clear a range within the column that will be hidden. I need to clear the data from row 7, 10, & 13:28 of the column that will be hidden.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub RemoveItem()
Dim i As Long
For i = 20 To 7 Step -1
    If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then
        bfirst = True
        Columns(i).Hidden = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be done better, but the below code will get the job done:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long

For i = 20 To 7 Step -1  
    If Columns(i).Hidden = False Then  
        bfirst = True  
        Columns(i).Hidden = True
        Rows(7).ClearContents  
        Rows(10).ClearContents  
        Range(Cells(13, i), Cells(28, i)).ClearContents  
    End If  
Next

End Sub
```